# How do I integrate WooCommerce into a custom HTML theme?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I know how to use WooCommerce but even then, how could I integrate WooCommerce into my own HTML theme?

Comment: Do you want to use custom design for woocommerce pages? and please add some related code

Comment: yes..I am use custom design page..but yet I can't start design so. please tell me If I will have done my design than how integrate with woo commerce .

Comment: You can just edit css files according to your requirement.... Also you can put woocommerce template file in your theme or child theme and you can easly edit these files

Answer (score 0):

You can just edit CSS files according to your requirement... Also you can put a WooCommerce template file in your theme or in child theme and you can easily edit these files.

If you want to a user WooCommerce template in the theme then create a WooCommerce folder in your theme and copy the WooCommerce plugin template to this folder.